# what data type returns a join query like this in java?

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I do not know what kind of data it returns this query and how to retrieve/use them

```
Query q1 = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT t.idb, c.value FROM trans t join com c  On t.id = c.idTrans where c.date >= '2014-05-01' AND c.date <= '2014-05-31' AND currency = 'euro' ORDER BY t.idb");
return q1.getResultList();
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? I think you will get back an Object array if you just use it like this out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on if you use getResultList or getSingleResult.  If you expect multiple rows to match the query, you would use getResultList and have a List containing an Object[] representing each row, with values matching the type returned from the driver for t.idb and c.value.

If you use getSingleResult, you would get an Object[] representing the only row that should have been returned, or a NonUniqueResultException if more than one row was returned from the query.

Comment: Hi Chris, I use getResultList(). Now i don t know how get data from Object[]. Usually a use something like that:    ((entity.SomeEntity)somelist.get(index)).someEntityGetMethod()

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I think you want to call [`getResultList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList%28%29) -

```
final List<Object> data = (List<Object>) query.getResultList();
```